# ReferenceError: raygunUtilityFactory is not defined

Tags: react-native, raygun

I am trying to implement raygun for a react-native app. I am running into problems with jest and I am not sure of the best approach given the window does not exist. In my package.json I have already added the following:

```
"globals": {
  "window": {}
}
```

I get the following error though and I am unable to resolve it as of yet:

```
ReferenceError: raygunUtilityFactory is not defined
```

This is a very basic implementation as per the docs:
https://raygun.com/docs/languages/javascript#reactnative

I presume this is something with jest but having searched on github, here and google I still have not been able to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raygun4JS does not currently work correctly in a non-browser environment. Your best bet would be to not include the Raygun4JS code inside of your test environment (which is what we do at Raygun) but that is a bit more complicated using the UMD module from NPM (we use the snippet approach to inject it dynamically).

I think the problem stems from `window` not being considered the global object in Jest vs the browser, we have an indirect call to the window object to call the `raygunUtilityFactory`. Are you using the `jsdom` test environment? We also have the same `window` definition in our jestconfig.json and export some variables onto `window` in our setupframework.js file that are accessed indirectly through the global object and it appears to work correctly.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue using jest mocks. However, regarding your comments-Raygun4JS do state in their docs that it is configured for react-native so I would be interested to know more about how it is not correctly working in a non browser environment as it may make me re consider. https://raygun.com/docs/languages/javascript#reactnative

Comment: React Native operates closely enough to a browser environment that Raygun4JS works in it. We still had to make some specific changes to get it to work however, those changes are behind React Native specific guards.